# Run two diffrent js files for two different div of same name in same html file

Tags: html

I have a div element which content is decided by the js file imported. Earlier I used to have two different html pages for two divs hence I had created two js files for each page (which will set the content according to the page requirements). Now I want to put them in a single scrollable html page.

Is it possible to run two seperate js files for div1 and div2 (something like code below) which are setting content of div id: foo?

I am preferring not changing the div id name foo, because the actual code contains many elements and is like a template.

```js
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = "content 1";
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = "content 2";
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="foo">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <div id="foo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: id need to be unique

Comment: you can not define same id with same html if you create diff html than it will be no metter but you use in same html its not good

Comment: so no solution for this either you can use diff id or use diff html for this

Comment: I will have to go ahead with changing the ids then, thanks

Comment: these ids also have associated styles with them, this means they also need to be replicated with different names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I have to do this because the html templates are generated by a third party.

I use a function to find the correct div:

```
function findthecorrectdiv(parentid,thecorrectdivid)
{
 var thecorrectdiv=document.getElementById(thecorrectdivid);
 var parent=thecorrectdiv?thecorrectdiv.parentNode:{};
 return(parent.id&&parent.id===parentid)?thecorrectdiv:{};
}
```

Then get the right div and fill it with awesome content:

```
var thecorrectdiv;
thecorrectdiv=findthecorrectdiv('div1','foo');
thecorrectdiv.innerHtml='awesome content 1';

thecorrectdiv=findthecorrectdiv('div2','foo');
thecorrectdiv.innerHtml='awesome content 2';
```

You'll probably put this in a loop - declare `var thecorrectdiv` before the loop starts.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have two divs with the same id `foo`. Id's need to be unique. Just change one of the id's and it should work fine.

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="foo"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> /// script 1 running for div1
     document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = "content 1"; 
</script>

<div id="div2">
    <div id="foo1"></div> <!-- CHANGED HERE -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> /// script 2 running for div2
     document.getElementById('foo1').innerHTML = "content 2"; /* AND HERE */
</script>
```